# How can I scroll to a specific div on a different page reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have something like this https://codesandbox.io/s/nav-to-specific-div-on-page-mljbqr?file=/src/App1.js where I have a "Next Page" button which takes me to a different page (Page Two), and on this page there's another button that should take me back to the div with the id "section-four" on the Main page and scroll down to that div.

I'm not entirely sure how to do this using refs, I can get it working if the div is on the same page, but not on a separate page like in this example

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to add an id to the section you want to go.

```
<div id="sctionToGo" />
```

Then from the Page 2 Button, you need to set the href like below.
If you are using react-router then it would be something like this:

```
<Link to="/page1#sectionTogo"> Button 2 </Link>
```

So in the href you need to add the section id with a "#" at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, tried it but it just takes me to the top of the previous page, not at the id

Comment: Can you show your code, how you are adding it?

Comment: updated the sandbox link, go to /app1 for the default /main page